# Liferay set the id of liferay-ui:search-container-row

Tags: javascript, liferay, alloy-ui

I want to set the `id` of the `tr` that is the result of the tag `liferay-ui:search-container-row`, how can I do it?

For Example, the resulting table row is:

`<tr id="aui_3_4_0_1_350" class="portlet-section-header results-header">`

I want to attach some javascript for the resulting table and I need something to refer to the various table row, like `id="aui_3_4_0_1_350"`.
I could also use the `class selector`, but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not posible to set a customized id value to a search-container-row. Because they get generated based on the input list and Ids need to be unique. However you can access it using a selector starting with the search-container itself. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you're using jQuery or similar it should be easy since there's a good variety of them: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give an element an id you should do it with `setAttribute` 
For example, you first need to get a reference to the element that you want to give the id, with:

```
var id = document.querySelector("p").setAttribute("id", "idName");
```

if this is what you're looking for.